# C# Deserialize XML to correct class type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I am using the `XmlSerializer` to do some serialization work. I was wondering if it is possible to "generically" deserialize from the XmlDocuement.

Concrete: If I have an XML File I would watch the tag and compare it with my DTO Model. Is this possible (better: Does .NET support this?) ? Maybe using an XSD file or something?

---

Example (without generic deserialization):

```
        XmlDocument myDocument = new XmlDocument();
        myDocument.Load(xml);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        myDocument.Save(stream);

        // Here I would like to use an interface instead and load the correct type of object.
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

        MyClass myObject;

        serializer.Serialize(stream, myObject);
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to map an XML which is not perfectly aligned to your DTO?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I want to map an XML to my perfectly aligned DTO. But I am loading different types of XML-Files. Then I have to check the XmlDocument for the tag where I define the object type. Is it possible to solve this using a generic approach. If I use an interface to deserialize the object.

Comment: you might be able to do what you want using a dynamic object for reading your xml, and then using reflection on your dto.  [This](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/kevin-hazzard/fluent-xml-parsing-using-cs-dynamic-type-part-1) is somewhere to start

Comment: Lots of XMLs to one class file? I would say use `XDocument` and just write a parser for each file type. At least minor changes to one doc isn't going to affect other documents.

Comment: I dont want to deserialize lots of XMLs into one class file. I want to use an XSD to use the correct class when deserializing without having to parse for the tags first. I am trying to delete all XML-Parsing inside my application and  let  the .NET Framework handle it, if  possible.

Comment: Is it maybe possible to compare my XmlDocument with my DTO Models?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is that you pre parse the xml file so you understand the class to create.
You could also write somewhere (in the file extension? in an attribute of the first element of the doc?) the class type.
When you have the class type you can create the right class via a switch statement (converting a string to a type) or via reflection (better).